# Find an li in a ul and compare it

Tags: html, css

I got this markup, I need to find an `li` in a given `ul` that has a `data-rank` with a number greater than the rest, and do something different with it, but only to an `li` in relation with its siblings.

Is there a clever way I can do this with normal css or maybe styled components?

```
<ul>
  <li data-rank='1'>Person1
    <ul>More li here</ul>
  </li>
    
  <li data-rank='1'>
    Person2
    <ul>More li here</ul>
  </li>

  <!-- I want to style this li because its siblings have a different number -->
  <li data-rank='2'>
    Person3
    <ul>More li here</ul>
  </li>

  <li data-rank='1'>
    Person4
    <ul>More li here</ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: JavaScript could easily do it

Comment: No, CSS on its own can not determine which of those data-rank values is the highest.

Answer (score 0):

With modern css you can snipe an `html` tag through their attribute like this:

```css
li[data-rank="2"] { margin: 50px; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-rank='1'>Person1
    <ul>More li here</ul>
  </li>
    
  <li data-rank='1'>
    Person2
    <ul>More li here</ul>
  </li>

  <!-- I want to style this li because its siblings have a different number -->
  <li data-rank='2'>
    Person3
    <ul>More li here</ul>
  </li>

  <li data-rank='1'>
    Person4
    <ul>More li here</ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

However check for browsers compatibility.

Good luck with your project, "tocayo".

Comment: Yeah but that is hard coded, I needed to be whatever number in relation to the other numbers

Comment: Javascript then. You may need to add the tag and edit the question